# in tabular environment, b{} doesn't do what it is supposed to do

Tags: tables, color

As described in the title. I have a tabular environment where I would like to make the text appeared at the bottom. However, the behavior is not what I expected. In the last line, only the first column appear at the bottom. Also, the cell is too large even though I have never used any strut.  However, the first column did what I wanted but not the second. [image]
Is there some bug or did I made some dumb mistake?
My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\title{\color{white} 颠覆传统教学模式，打造中国双师名牌\\ {\tiny 宣传§话术§理论基础}}
\date{}
\author{}
\maketitle



\section{什么是浸入式教学}
\pagecolor{purple}



所谓浸入式(Immersion)是指用第二语言作为教学语言的教学模式。第二语言不仅是学习的内容，而且是学习的工具。该教学方式起源于加拿大魁北克地区，近年来因其显著的成效而被世界各地的语言学习者所推崇。



\section{和传统教学模式的比较}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{5pt}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{DB5800}
\begin{tabular}{b{0.3\textwidth}b{0.5\textwidth}}
\hline
\cellcolor{blue}{浸入式教学}&\cellcolor{red}{传统课堂}\\
\cellcolor{blue!70}{以学生为中心}&\cellcolor{red!70}{以教师为中心}\\
\cellcolor{blue!30}{主动式学习}&\cellcolor{red!30}{被动式学习}\\
\cellcolor{blue!70}{多个知识点形成整体}&\cellcolor{red!30}{孤立知识点，互相之间无联系}


\end{tabular}



\section{为什么选择仕言}



\section{Q\&A}



\end{document}
```

Comment: In the title of the question you mention an m type column, in the code you only use b. Please clarify.

Comment: I have changed it to b, but both act very weird

Comment: remove the empty lines before \end{tabular}.